# How to list all file names in terminal?

Tags: files

Let's say I want a list of files in the Downloads folder to be viewed from the terminal. How would I do that?

Comment: `ls ~/Downloads` maybe?

Comment: Are you going to make any attempt to search yourself before asking more of these questions?

Comment: It's related to your downloder software.

Comment: You can use "ls" command to list the files and folders available in the directory. In case if you wanted to the whole list of files available under sub directory try "tree" command and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is the best choice. Type `man ls` for more information.